# Database schema initially not designed for scaling, how to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I developped 2 years ago a back office for helping a logistic company to manage the deliveries.
At this time, the company only had one "partner" (let's call it **Partner A**).

The main table is `delivery_note`.

I tried to design the database to be the more generic as possible. 
So I decided to put all the partner related fields in a dedicated table.

But two years later, we have **5 partners** (and more are incoming) and I don't like to add a new FK in `delivery_note` each time we add a new partner.

The relation between a `delivery_note` and a `partner` is 1 1 (optional). In practice a `delivery_note` can be linked to only one `partner`.

The schema looks like:

[image]

Do you know any pattern or way to design a more flexible schema to handle this case ?

Thank you

Comment: Are "partners" like UPS/Fedex/DHL??

Comment: Is there a lot of redundancy in the "seller"?  That is, perhaps the many columns related to the "seller" (name address, phone, lat/lng) should be moved to a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your design a bit backword, can a delivery_note_partner_A exist without a corresponding delivery_note?

Assuming that is not the case, I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE delivery_note
( delivery_note_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
);
```

Depending on how much processing of the notes for each partner you are going to do, you may consider something like:

```
CREATE TABLE delivery_note_partner
( delivery_note_partner_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, delivery_note_id ... NOT NULL REFERENCES delivery_note (delivery_note_id)
, delivery_note JSON NOT NULL
);
```

Whether the partner should reside in the JSON doc or as an attribute is a decision to make

EDIT:
After some discussion in a separate thread, this is the suggestion I proposed:

```
-- removed attributes delivery_not_parter_X
CREATE TABLE delivery_note (
 delivery_note_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (delivery_note_id),
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_1E21328E551F0F81` (`order_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- sample data with above attributes removed
INSERT INTO `delivery_note` (`delivery_note_id`, `status`, `seller_name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `street`, `street_extra`, `post_code`, `city`, `lat`, `lng`, `phone_number`, `phone_number2`, `residential_type`, `floor`, `elevator`, `service_type`, `order_number`, `order_picker_name`, `order_flow_origin`, `delivery_day`, `delivery_hour_start`, `delivery_hour_end`, `observation`, `internal_observation`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `delivered_at`, `route_plan_order_id`, `route_customer_id`, `route_route_id`, `delivery_dday`) VALUES
(1, 'delivered',    'Sauvage',  'Adrien',   'Thibault', 'spotier@wanadoo.fr',   '16 rue des violettes', NULL,   '77500',    'Chelles',  48.89320500,    2.59495500, '0476134831',   NULL,   'house',    'fourth',   0,  'comfort',  '32027253', NULL,   'store_order',  '2020-01-02 00:46:52',  '2019-12-30 15:23:47',  '2019-12-30 16:45:03',  NULL,   NULL,   '2019-12-30 12:11:31',  '2019-12-30 12:11:31',  NULL,   93004,  8782,   NULL,   0),
...);    
-- new table
CREATE TABLE delivery_note_partner 
( delivery_note_partner_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, delivery_note_id int(11) NOT NULL
, delivery_note JSON NOT NULL
  -- example of generated column, for indexing purposes
, payment_method varchar(20) generated always as (delivery_note ->> '$.payment_method')
,     CONSTRAINT PK_DELIVERY_NOTE_PARTNER  
          PRIMARY KEY (delivery_note_partner_id)
,     CONSTRAINT AK1_DELIVERY_NOTE_PARTNER 
          UNIQUE (delivery_note_id)
,     CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_NOTE 
          FOREIGN KEY (delivery_note_id)
          REFERENCES delivery_note (delivery_note_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Since MySQL does not support indexes on JSON, this is an example of an index for attributes that are used in predicates

CREATE INDEX X01_DELIVERY_NOTE_PARTNER ON delivery_note_partner (payment_method);

-- some migrated sample data for new table
INSERT INTO delivery_note_partner (delivery_note_id, delivery_note)
VALUES (1, '{ "payment_method":"credit_card", "total_price_amount": 6500, "total_price_currency":"EUR" }')
    ,  (12, '{ "client_account_number":"ACC605739261" }')
    ,  (17, '{ "sum_owed_amount":7500, "sum_owed_currency":"EUR", "delivery_price_amount":2500, "delivery_price_currency":"EUR" }');
```

Comment: [Discussion has been moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102675/discussion-between-adrien-g-and-lennart).

Comment: here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53c6a800f0450c9addae32ae182868a6